# Charts are not matching up one is centered the other is left justified in matplotlib

Tags: python

Im Trying to make a stock chart this is what I have.
A candle stick chart of the price with a overlapping moving averg.  On the button is a bar chart of the vol.

The issue is the candle stick chart and vol chart are centered, while the moving averg is right justified.  Thus when the moving averg chart overlaps the candle stick, they are not lines up on the x axes.
(UPDATE: I just added two more charts at the buttom that use the plot methed, they are left justified to, it seems like al the charts I do using plot are left justified while the res are centered)

I use ax2v = ax2.twinx() to get the moving averg to be on same graph as candle stick.  Ax2 is for candle stick, ax2v is for moving averg.

I did look this up and stack overflow and saw some one said you add  align='center', IO tried  thatv as follows
ax2v.plot(bit.slowMacd[macdStart:], align='center')
and got a error saying TypeError: There is no Line2D property "align"

The code snippet for the candle stick and moving averg chart

#

```
### SET UO CANDLE STICK CHART
x = 0
y = len(bit.listAll)

ohlc = []
while x < y:
    append_me = bit.listAll[x], bit.openPrice[x], bit.biggestPrice[x], bit.smallestPrice[x], bit.closePrice[x], bit.vol[x]
    ohlc.append(append_me)
    x+=1
candlestick_ohlc(ax2, ohlc[macdStart:], width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')
```

ax2v.plot(bit.slowMacd[macdStart:], align='center')

The complete program
def drawGraph():

```
#######################################################################
# Set up chart postions and title
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
plt.title("Test")
plt.ylabel('H-L')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
plt.ylabel('Price')
ax2v = ax2.twinx()
#ax2v2 = ax2.twinx()

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
plt.ylabel('MAvgs')
######################################################################

######################################################################
### SET UO CANDLE STICK CHART
x = 0
y = len(bit.listAll)

ohlc = []
while x < y:
    append_me = bit.listAll[x], bit.openPrice[x], bit.biggestPrice[x], bit.smallestPrice[x], bit.closePrice[x], bit.vol[x]
    ohlc.append(append_me)
    x+=1
candlestick_ohlc(ax2, ohlc[macdStart:], width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')
ax2v.plot(bit.slowMacd[macdStart:], align='center')
#ax2v.plot(bit.fastMacd[macdStart:], , align='center')
#####################################################################

#####################################################################
### VOL CHART
ax3.fill_between(bit.listAll,0, bit.vol, facecolor='#0079a3')




plt.show()

ax2v.plot(bit.slowMacd[macdStart:])
#ax2v.plot(bit.fastMacd[macdStart:], , align='center')
#####################################################################
```

Comment: The issue is most likely with how the call to `ax2.plot` is being made in `candlestick_ohlc`, however because *we* do not know what `candlestick_ohlc` does, we cannot clarify and it is up to you to add details. It is my *guess* that `candlestick_ohlc` adds the independant variable in the plotting of the candlesticks (the time-scale, most likely), and your call to `ax2v.plot(bit.slowMacd....` does not. Please clarify the following things: where does `candlestick_ohlc` come from (give its implementation if you made it yourself) and specify the details of the variables `ohlc` and `bit.slowMacd`.

Comment: I took out the cpode to draw the candle stick chart and moving averg chart.  I have two charts at the botton.

Comment: I took out the top code for candle stick and moving averg.  The bottom has code to draw the vol as a bar grap with the folllowing line of code ax3.fill_between(bit.listAll[macdStart:],0, bit.vol[macdStart:], facecolor='#0079a3') and is centered tghe other chart is a line chart and usses the same data vol but is not centered ax5.plot(RateOfChange[macdStart:]) does any one know how I can get both of thses charts to be ceyered or roght justified???

Comment: You're not getting the comment I made: please update your post to include the relevant information. There is indeed no `align` keyword for a plotted line. Your issue stems (most likely) from not having the two datasets in the middle figure aligned by their x-data.